# DocuSign - Signature part from JWT configuration

Tags: docusignapi, jwt

Following [this](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token) tutorial I'm stuck with figuring out what the part of the signature is supposed to keep.

What is the final struct from the JWT to request access token?
What I'm using is this string:
`Base64UrlEncoded(header).Base64UrlEncoded(body).RSASHA256(Base64UrlEncoded(header).Base64UrlEncoded(body), provided_private_rsa_key)`

Is this the supposed way of doing it? What I've noticed is that the tutorial in the signature part shows an example completely different from what they describe.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What coding lang do you use?

Comment: I'm stuck in a similar spot. What they need is some sort of code example. I'm doing the same thing you're doing and it's not working...

Comment: Inbar Gazir I'm using Elixir as my language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [JWT.IO](https://jwt.io/introduction/), it looks like the format of the signature should be `RSASHA256(base64UrlEncode(header) + "." + base64UrlEncode(payload), secret)`. If the periods in your code don't correspond to literal `.`s, then those would need to be added.

I'd recommend taking the assertion you're generating and plugging it in to [JWT.IO's Debugger](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io) along with your public key to confirm you've generated a valid assertion.

Comment: Yeah, you were right, that was my mistake. Sorry for the delayed response!